# How to get the gradient of the loss function during the training process with spark 2.0?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Currently, we are working on Spark 2.0, and I want to know how gradient of loss function was changed during the spark training, which can be used to visualize the training process.
For example, I have the following code:

```
// Load training data in LIBSVM format.
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

// Split data into training (60%) and test (40%).
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 11L)
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1)

// Run training algorithm to build the model
val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
  .setNumClasses(10)
  .run(training)
```

and I know there are some classes under package "org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation" can be used to get some metrics from the model, but I am still not able to know how the gradient of loss function was changed during the training process.

is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `spark-mllib` doesn't support that type of query and it won't be supporting it anytime soon as it's deprecated.

On the other hand, you can use spark-ml 's version of the `LogisticRegression` with `binomial` family (the only one supported for now). Thus you can compute the loss function as followed :

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
scala> val training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("./data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")
// training: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [label: double, features: vector]

scala> val lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.3).setElasticNetParam(0.8)
// lr: org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression = logreg_ea4e7cd94045

scala> val lrModel = lr.fit(training)
// 17/04/10 11:51:19 WARN LogisticRegression: LogisticRegression training finished but the result is not converged because: max iterations reached
// lrModel: org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel = logreg_ea4e7cd94045

scala> val trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
trainingSummary: org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionTrainingSummary = org.apache.spark.ml.classification.BinaryLogisticRegressionTrainingSummary@2878abcd

scala> val objectiveHistory = trainingSummary.objectiveHistory
// objectiveHistory: Array[Double] = Array(0.6833149135741672, 0.6662875751473734, 0.6217068546034619, 0.6127265245887887, 0.6060347986802872, 0.6031750687571562, 0.5969621534836274, 0.5940743031983119, 0.5906089243339021, 0.589472457649104, 0.5882187775729588)

scala> objectiveHistory.foreach(loss => println(loss))
// 0.6833149135741672
// 0.6662875751473734
// 0.6217068546034619
// 0.6127265245887887
// 0.6060347986802872
// 0.6031750687571562
// 0.5969621534836274
// 0.5940743031983119
// 0.5906089243339021
// 0.589472457649104
// 0.5882187775729588
```

I hope this helps.

**PS:** This solution works for spark 1.6 as well.

Comment: as you mentioned, only LogisticRegression support to get loss function in such a way, I just wondering if there any plan to provide summary functions   to all other training methods, such as KMeans, DecisionTree, etc.